# Convert a list of values to a list of intervals in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of objects, each containing a `flag` (boolean) and a `value` (integer). The value is increasing for each list item. I want to convert the list into a new list with only the first and last value property (the interval) for every time the flag property alternates.

In other words, I want to convert this

```
[
    {'flag': True, 'value': 0},
    {'flag': True, 'value': 5},
    {'flag': True, 'value': 10}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 15}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 20},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 25}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 30},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 35},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 40}, 
    {'flag': True, 'value': 45},
    {'flag': True, 'value': 50},
    {'flag': True, 'value': 55}, 
    {'flag': True, 'value': 60},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 65},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 70}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 75},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 80},
    {'flag': False, 'value': 85}, 
    {'flag': True, 'value': 90},
    {'flag': True, 'value': 95}
]
```

into this (or something similar):

```
[
    {'flag': True, 'values': (0, 10)}, 
    {'flag': False, 'values': (15, 40)}, 
    {'flag': True, 'values': (45, 60)}, 
    {'flag': False, 'values': (65, 85)}, 
    {'flag': True, 'values': (90, 95)}, 
]
```

What is a simple and elegant way of solving this in Python?

I hope the example data isn't too confusing. I've tried solving this both using a for-loop and using reduce, but neither solution seems right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the items by `flag` and then convert the groups to lists and get the values of the first and last elements of those lists. Here, `lst` is your original list.

```
>>> [{"flag": key, "values" : (val[0]["value"], val[-1]["value"])} 
...  for key, val in ((key, list(val)) for key, val in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda d: d["flag"]))]
[{'flag': True, 'values': (0, 10)},
 {'flag': False, 'values': (15, 40)},
 {'flag': True, 'values': (45, 60)},
 {'flag': False, 'values': (65, 85)},
 {'flag': True, 'values': (90, 95)}]
```

Or similar, using an inner list comprehension to extract the `value` keys first, as we have to use an inner generator expression to convert the group iterator to list anyway. The result is the same.

```
>>> [{"flag": key, "values" : (vals[0], vals[-1])}
...  for key, vals in ((key, [g["value"] for g in grp]) 
...                    for key, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda d: d["flag"]))]
```

But that's still far from being readable, so I'd suggest splitting this up into two lines:

```
>>> groups = ((key, [g["value"] for g in grp])
...           for key, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda d: d["flag"]))
>>> result = [{"flag": key, "values" : (vals[0], vals[-1])} for key, vals in groups]
```

Comment: Can't find any better way of doing this with python tools, however, since author asked for the most pythonic way of doing this, I'd say the massive comprehension list isn't helping the readability of the code, and I'd go for the same answer with for loops.

Comment: @T.Nel Agree that this is not as simple and "pythonic" as one might wish, but I don't think that a "manual" solution with loops would be better. Better split it up into several lines. Also, you can always wrap those things into well-named and documented functions.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas solution:

```
j = [
{'flag': True, 'value': 0}, {'flag': True, 'value': 5}, 
{'flag': True, 'value': 10}, {'flag': False, 'value': 15}, 
{'flag': False, 'value': 20}, {'flag': False, 'value': 25}, 
{'flag': False, 'value': 30}, {'flag': False, 'value': 35}, 
{'flag': False, 'value': 40}, {'flag': True, 'value': 45}, 
{'flag': True, 'value': 50}, {'flag': True, 'value': 55}, 
{'flag': True, 'value': 60}, {'flag': False, 'value': 65}, 
{'flag': False, 'value': 70}, {'flag': False, 'value': 75}, 
{'flag': False, 'value': 80}, {'flag': False, 'value': 85}, 
{'flag': True, 'value': 90}, {'flag': True, 'value': 95}]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(j)

df['group'] = df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum() # column to groupby 
output = df.groupby("group").apply(lambda x: \
                                   {'flag':x["flag"].tolist()[0], 
                                    'values':(x["value"].min(),x["value"].max())})

output.tolist()
```

Outputs:

```
[{'flag': True, 'values': (0, 10)},
 {'flag': False, 'values': (15, 40)},
 {'flag': True, 'values': (45, 60)},
 {'flag': False, 'values': (65, 85)},
 {'flag': True, 'values': (90, 95)}]
```

Dataframe looks like:

```
    flag    value   group
0   True    0   1
1   True    5   1
2   True    10  1
3   False   15  2
4   False   20  2
5   False   25  2
6   False   30  2
7   False   35  2
8   False   40  2
9   True    45  3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Manual solution:

```
lista = [
    {'flag': True, 'value': 0}, {'flag': True, 'value': 5}, {'flag': True, 'value': 10}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 15}, {'flag': False, 'value': 20}, {'flag': False, 'value': 25}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 30}, {'flag': False, 'value': 35}, {'flag': False, 'value': 40}, 
    {'flag': True, 'value': 45}, {'flag': True, 'value': 50}, {'flag': True, 'value': 55}, 
    {'flag': True, 'value': 60}, {'flag': False, 'value': 65}, {'flag': False, 'value': 70}, 
    {'flag': False, 'value': 75}, {'flag': False, 'value': 80}, {'flag': False, 'value': 85}, 
    {'flag': True, 'value': 90}, {'flag': True, 'value': 95}
]
change = False
output = []
p=[0]*2
flagPast = lista[0]['flag']
for index,item in enumerate(lista):
    if(item['flag'] != flagPast):
        cp=p[:]       
        output.append(zip(['flag','values'],[flagPast,cp]))
        p[0]=item['value']
        change = True
    else:
        change = False
    if(not(change)):
        p[1]=item['value']
    flagPast = item['flag']
    if(index==(len(lista)-1)):
        p[1]=item['value']        
        cp=p[:]       
        output.append(zip(['flag','values'],[flagPast,cp]))
```